# correct use of boost::wait boost::condition

Tags: c++, boost, mutex

```
boost::condition cond;
boost::recursive_mutex mutex;

for(;;)
{
    D * d = nullptr;

    while( cb.pop(d) ) 
    {

    }

    boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock( **mutex** );
    cond.wait( **mutex** );
}


while(1)
{
    getchar();

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i )
    {
        cb.push(new D(i));           
        boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock( **mutex** );
        cond.notify_one();
    }
}
```

My doubt is about the mutex, I only need on mutex object ?

EDIT:

cb is a circular buffer.
I want to implement a sort of producer-consumer pattern

do I have to use the same mutex for wait and notify_one ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is cb? Why are these infinite loops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using a recent version of boost, `boost::condition` is the same thing as `boost::condition_variable_any`, which I believe is the same thing as `std::condition_variable_any`.

If all that is true, or at least approximately true, your code should compile, but will probably deadlock if you call `cond.wait(mutex)` with `mutex` recursively locked.

I recommend instead:

```
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex mutex;

// In one thread

for(;;)
{
    D * d = nullptr;

    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock( mutex );
    while( cb.pop(d) ) 
    {

    }
    while (cb.empty())
       cond.wait( lock );
}

// In another thread

while(1)
{
    getchar();

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i )
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock( mutex );
        cb.push(new D(i));           
        cond.notify_one();
    }
}
```

And if your implementation supports it, substitute `std` for `boost`.  This:

1. Doesn't use a recursive mutex.  Be sure you don't try to lock it recursively.
2. Uses the mutex to protect access to your container `cb`.
3. Uses a while loop around your wait to guard against spurious wakeups.
4. Uses the much cheaper `condition_variable` instead of the more expensive (and more flexible) `condition_variable_any`.  I'm not seeing the need for the latter in your example.

Comment: the direct disadvantage of your design is that it blocks the producer to push while the consumer pop..in case of a streaming algo is a little bit inefficient imo, isn't it ?

Comment: If your `cb` doesn't need to be protected from asynchronous access, then by all means move it out from under the protection of the mutex.  I have no idea if your `cb` will do that or not.  My main point is that you don't want to wait on a recursively locked mutex using `condition_variable_any`.

Comment: yes indeed cb don't need.ok I will get a  look at condition_variable, thanks for your answer. Oh and to finish, the boost::recursive_mutex, is really more time consuming than boost::mutex ?

Comment: The probably depends on the platform and the answer is probably not really.  However, `condition_variable_any` (aka `condition`) *is* considerably more expensive than `condition_variable`.  And `condition_variable` will fail at compile time if you try to wait on it with anything other than a `unique_lock<mutex>`.

Comment: Oh, but if you wait on a `condition_variable_any` with a `recursive_mutex` which has a lock count greater than 1, then your notifying thread will never be able to obtain the lock on that `recursive_mutex`.  Thus you have deadlock (infinitely more time consuming).

Comment: ok in fact I don't well understand the difference between condition and condition_any, the boost documentation is pretty dry about that

Comment: @HowardHinnant let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1577/discussion-between-guillaume07-and-howard-hinnant)

Answer (score 0):

Correct - you need one mutex; it's purpose will be to make sure that multiple consumers are synchronized with the respect to your one producer.

Also, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html